# Returning an error message if no resultes are found in LINQ query for model

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

I built an edit page to update data and it works fine if the correct ID is passed in but when an invalid ID is passed in I get a null reference exception. I know this is due to the fact the LINQ query does not find any valid data from the database but I am not sure how to deal with this unless I add a bunch of `IF` statements in my view to check for null every time I reference the model. Here is the code I currently have for the controller.

```
    public ActionResult EditSection(Int16 id = -1)
    {
        Section section = db.Sections.Find(id);
        SectionAddEditVM model = new SectionAddEditVM { Section = section };

        if (section != null)
        {
            if (section.Type == "Collection")
            {
                RedirectToAction("Collection", new { id = id });
            }

            model.SelectedType = section.Type;
            return View(model);
        }

        ModelState.AddModelError("Section ID", "Invalid Section ID");
        return View(model);
    }
```

View:

```
@model SectionAddEditVM

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit " + Model.Section.Title + " Information";
}

<h2>
    Edit @Model.Section.Title Information
</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken();
    @Html.ValidationSummary(false)

    <p>
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Section.ID)
        <label for="Title">Seciton Title:</label> @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Section.Title)
        <br />
        <label for="RouteName">Section Route:</label> @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Section.RouteName)
        <br />
        <label for="Type">Section Type:</label> @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Section.Type, new SelectList(Model.Type, "Value", "Text"))
        <br />
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Section.LogoFileID)
        <label for="LogoFile">Logo Image:</label> <input id="LogoFile" name="LogoFile" type="file" />
        <br />
        <label for="Synopsis">Synopsis:</label> @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Section.Synopsis)
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Edit Information" />
    </p>
}
```

Comment: Where does the null reference exception happen in your code above? In new SectionAddEditVM? Or do you already account for it with if (section != null)

Comment: The null reference exception happens in the view when ever I reference the model. I added the view code for reference.

Comment: Why would you need a lot of if statements in the view?  A single if statement would take care of this...`if(model == null){output message}else{do stuff}.  Or, instead of a modelstate error, redirect to an error view that basically says your request contained invalid data.

Comment: Indeed, what do you want it to do when no section is found? Error page?

Comment: Have you considered either passing something that is NOT null to the view when there isn't anything in the database. OR as is the typical case with HTTP, return a `404 Not Found`?

Comment: I don't want to return an HTTP 404 or redirect to another page, I want to print out an error message to the existing page, and since I am getting the null reference when ever the view tries to access the model the only way I know how to deal with this is to wrap each model call in the view with an if statement or wrap the entire contents of the view in an if statement. Both of which are ugly and/or timeous.

Comment: @Aron Do you mean fill each property in the model with zero character strings? That thought did occur to me about 2 minutes after posting the question.

Comment: 404 does not preclude sending another View to the user. 404 does not mean redirect. 404 is much more RESTful and consumers will thank you for having a sane API that adheres to HTTP.

Comment: @MatthewVerstraete Yes you could. You could just leave the properties as null (unless there is nesting). However I really would advise to have a 404 View.

Comment: @Aron if I leave the properties as null, won't that still through a null reference exception in the view? And, again, I must reiterate I do not want to return a 404.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add an `ELSE` clause and initialize a new, blank, model.

```
    public ActionResult EditSection(Int16 id = -1)
    {
        Section section = db.Sections.Find(id);

        if (section != null)
        {
            if (section.Type == "Collection")
            {
                RedirectToAction("Collection", new { id = id });
            }

            SectionAddEditVM model = new SectionAddEditVM { Section = section };
            model.SelectedType = section.Type;
            return View(model);
        }
        else
        {
            section = new Section();
            SectionAddEditVM model = new SectionAddEditVM { Section = section };

            ModelState.AddModelError("Section ID", "Invalid Section ID");
            return View(model);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Would be nice if the person who down voted this explained why. No one else gave me a solution to the issue I posted and my solution works.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you're already checking if `section` is `null`. So, in case it IS `null` just return a different view that says: "No section found" or something. Additionally (as suggested here by @Aron) you could return `404` status code with this view, so controller would look something like this:

```
// find section based on ID
// ... actual code ...
if (section != null)
{
    // process data and assign to model
    return View(model);
}
else
{
    Response.StatusCode = (int) System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
    return View("NoSectionFound");
}
```

Note that by returning a different view, you are not returning a different page. URL is still the same, since it's based on the controller not the view. By rendering a different view you avoid having to complicate the code in the view that normally displays the data.

BTW, avoid giving "too much" information like "Invalid section ID" which can direct potential attacker to where to "poke" next.

I'd also rearrange the code so you assign value to `model` only when section is found and for the "no section found" view you obviously don't need to pass any model.

Comment: Disagree. When you go to an invalid id on websites like imgur, facebook etc, you get a `404 Not Found`. Heck its so common that non-techs understand 404. If you worry about your ids being used to compromise the system, you can use non-sequencial ids like UUID/GUID.

Comment: What do you disagree specifically?

Comment: The check in the controller deals with it at the controller level but I still get null reference errors on the view level, and as stated in the original post I want to return an error message to the view. The error message in my posting's code is just basic right now in order to get things up and running and then grow out from there

Comment: Actually, reading more carefully...nothing...I would personally add use a 404 header along with the different View. As for "too much" information, that is simply a case of choosing your keys correctly.

Comment: @Matthew, I made edits to my original answer. However, if you absolutely must use the same view, then you'd have to wrap your whole view in `if (model != null) ... else` effectively doing the same check (as in controller) again. Code would be more clear if you just have a separate "no section found" view where your error message would be. Also, agree with @Aron about returning 404 status code with your "no section found" view.

Comment: @Floremin I must reiterate, I do not want to return a 404. I want a solution where I can pass up any error message I want and display the view.